# Database Insertion using ajax , not working

Tags: php, html, ajax, postgresql

I'm trying to insert data into a database using ajax and php , but this is not working. The connection with the database is working (tried it using only php). The ajax part of my code is posting and the values are valid (checked with firebug). I use postgresql for my data base
      I don't know why it doesn't work.
      When i press the comment button it works (i get no errors) , but the text in the fields doesn't go into the database

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(event) {
var name = $("#name").val();
var title= $('#title').val();
var comment= $('#comment').val();
$.post("comment.php", {name: name, title: title, comment: comment},

function (data) {
if (!data) {
$("#submit").append("Failed to reach server. Login Error.");
} else {
alert(data);
        }
});
return false; 
});
});
</script> 
<div class='comments'>
<!--<form action="scripts/comment.php" method="POST"> -->
<form action="" method="POST">
<label>Name:  </label><br /><input id="name"type="text" name="name" /><br /><br />
<label>Title: </label><br /><input id="title"type="text" name="title" /><br /><br />
<label>Comment:  </label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="90" rows="7">       </textarea><br /><br /><br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" /><br />

</form>
<hr width=auto size="5px" />
</div>
```

And the php for insertion:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
// attempt a connection
$conn_string = "host= port= dbname= user= password=";
$dbh = pg_connect($conn_string);
if (!$dbh)  {
die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}

$name =pg_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$title= pg_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$comment =pg_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$today=pg_escape_string(date('d-m-y'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES  ('$name','$comment','$today','$title',nextval('comments_id_seq'::regclass))";
$result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
if (!$result) {

die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
} 
pg_close($dbh);
//   $page='../index.php';
//header('Location:'.$page);
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated :) . Thanks

Comment: Well, there are syntax errors in the PHP code.  The syntax highlighting on this page points directly to a missing closing quote on the connection string.  Are you sure there are no errors in the PHP logs?

Comment: Start by putting a " at the end of your $conn_string

Comment: I suggest you put the date differently, at least as 'Y-m-d', or you will have difficulty ordering by date.

Comment: The error in the connection string appears because I removed the details from there when I posted the code. In the code I have there is a closing quote . Thanks

Comment: Turn on error reporting and see what your ajax response is.

Comment: Ajax response is POST to comment.php ok time 20ms , the values sent are the values I type in the forms . Ajax is reporting no errors .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $.post() call disregards the server's response which makes troubleshooting difficult. There are a few things you can to do correct this:

First, ensure that you have turned on PHP error reporting. If it is not turned on in your config, enable it near the beginning of your script like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Next, find a way to see the output of your PHP script. You can modify your `post` call to receive and process the response, but an easier way is to temporarily post your HTML form directly to the script bypassing the AJAX call. See what output the script produces when you post the form directly to the script.

Comment: Hi, i tried to bypass the ajax call and the php works correctly, everything gets inserted into the database. I also added the php error reporting bit and i get no error with or without the ajax call. When i use ajax i get this report POST http://localhost:8888/My%20SIte/scripts/comment.php
 
200 OK
  3.37s

Comment: @Liviu Is the correct path /scripts/comment.php or /comment.php? Your AJAX call uses the latter, but your recent comment (and the commented form action in your original post) use the former.

Comment: Yes the path is correct, i copied comments.php to the main folder as well. So the file is in both the main folder and scripts.

Comment: If I were in your situation, I would first check my web server logs to see which script was executing (the one in /, or /scripts, or somewhere else). Then I would double-check that the scripts really are identical. I don't know how many times I have changed and debugged one script, only to find out that the webserver was executing a different one.

Finally, I would add more debugging output to the PHP script. Add die() statements liberally and see what you get back. For example, does the input data arrive intact? Does the DB connection really get opened?